# Is it possible to provide security for war file?

Tags: java, security, web-applications, war, code-access-security

I have developed a web application which I am going to sell, but I face some security issues because I am going to provide a `.war` file to client machines and I found `.war` files can be easily extracted.

How can one provide security for war files to avoid being copied or extracted?

While searching I found **Excelsior jet** which converts web apps to native code but it's a trial version and I cannot afford its price so I want to know other alternatives.

Comment: I believe if you convert your WAR file to native code, then you can't deploy it in a web container. Excelsior Jet is good for Java applications which are running out of container.

Answer (score 3):

A web app container cannot deploy an exe anyway. You can obfuscate your classes and maybe write a licensing module. If you prevent users from extracting your war you'll also prevent the container from deployment.

For example, you might use a Java Bytecode Obfuscater such as

- [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yguard_about.html)
- [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)
- [*JODE*](http://jode.sourceforge.net/)

As for a licensing module, you may be able to use
[this](http://blog.patrikdufresne.com/2012/04/licensing-module-for-java.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610002/java-license-manager-validation-licence-issue).

Comment: Thanks for replying. but bro i really don't know how to obfuscate classes and how it work for web application war file on appache server can you provide me more detail or link please.

Answer (score 2):

The possible way is to

- Use code obfuscator
- Code in init() or somewhere check for license/access only one host.

Another option is to code your own classloader and implement it in modified web container

Comment: can you tell me how to code own classloader and how to implement it or give me link please

Comment: @Nilesh12 Trust the [Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-custom-class-loaders/184404138). The Dr. Dobbs is good.